# Is there a function to calculate studentized range?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

Is there a built-in function for [studentized range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range) or do I have to build it myself?

Is there a test of normality for the studentized range?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not think there's one built-in, but it's fairly easy to write a function for it:

```
studentizedRange[data_List] := (Max[data] - Min[data])/StandardDeviation[data]
```

But I would also check out the [ANOVA](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ANOVA/tutorial/ANOVA.html) package for related functionality.

Comment: yes thank you apparently there is the ducan test directly. however, the calculation is simple and there seems to be no direct function, so i just leave it with the manual calcs.

Answer (score 5):

Studentizing has been dealt with adequately by Eli. As to your second question: Normality tests can be performed with [DistributionFitTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistributionFitTest.html).